# How do I configure Rubymine to work with our folder structure?

Tags: rspec, rubymine

We're in the process of breaking up our Rails app into modules.  The main app has a (decreasing but still large) number of rspec tests under `spec/` and also each module has its own tests under `modules/[name]/spec/`.

To run the module tests correctly, it's necessary to change into the module folder before invoking `rspec`; so

```
bin/rspec modules/example/spec
```

won't work; but

```
cd modules/example; bundle exec rspec spec
```

will work.

I like to run my tests in RubyMine, especially when using the debugger.  For any given test run, I can change the working directory by creating a new Run/Debug configuration, and the tests will then run (and debug) correctly.  But I have to do that for every test run.  If I create a configuration for "all tests in modules/example/spec" then it will work if I right-click `modules/example/spec` and run the tests, but if I then run them for a subfolder, it won't.  If I set it up for a subfolder, that works for that subfolder, but not for a single file in that subfolder.  Ditto for a context in the file, or a single test in a context.  Parent configurations don't apply.  Those each need their own configuration.

Is there a way to tell RubyMine that if I start tests off inside `modules/example/spec` then it should use a particular configuration, irrespective of whether I'm running them for the whole folder or a single test?

I'd accept an answer which I needed to do once per module.  It's having to do it for every different possible subset that makes it unworkable.

Comment: Could you please attach screenshots of working and non-working run configurations? You mentioned that running all the tests in the folder works fine while running all of them in the subfolder doesn't. Which error do you get in this case?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a working or non-working configuration.  The configuration for, say, `modules/example/spec` works if I right-click on `modules/example/spec` and run the tests.. but it doesn't work if I right-click on `modules/example/spec/example_spec.rb`, because that configuration doesn't apply in that case.  In the latter case, my specs are run with the project folder as their working directory, and I get the error I'd expect to see if I ran them that way.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the problem in 2021.3 EAP but failed to do it (both Run configurations had the same working directory and in both cases spec tests ran). It'd be great to take a look at the project sample or project structure + created Run configurations.

Comment: The thing where tests won't run without a particular working directory isn't a bug in Rubymine, it's a property of our tests.  What I'm asking here is a way to configure Rubymine to run the tests with the working directory that they need, without having to reconfigure it on every test run.

Comment: It's not clear enough how IDE should recognize which folder to set. At the moment it's only possible to change the template or the created Run configurations, but it'd be great if you could submit a feature request specifying the expected behaviour: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/RUBY